# How to use column' value in subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have query like this.

```
SELECT col1,
       (SELECT another_col1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.date = col1) AS some_col
FROM table1
ORDER BY id;
```

But I can't use **col1** in subquery, it always returns last record but not matching.

How can I use it in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output. I have no idea what you mean with "*it always returns last record*"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should alias the tables ! Unless the columns you are comparing are unique, the optimizer will take each column on his current level, E.G. - if you are comparing in the correlated query, and the inner table has the same column name as the outer table, the optimizer will think you are meaning to compare the column from the inner table.

```
SELECT t.col1,
      (SELECT s.another_col1 FROM Table1 s WHERE s.date = t.col1) as some_col
FROM table1 t
ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: You should clarify why table aliases are very helpful, for future readers :P.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT (SELECT another_col1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.date = col1) as
 col1,(SELECT another_col1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.date = col1) AS
 some_col FROM (select col1 as col1 from table1) as col1 ORDER BY id;
```